# Flask - GET request depending on POST result to update template

Tags: python, flask, post, get, page-refresh

I am developping a python flask app to launch databricks jobs (executing IPython notebooks) without using databricks website.

I have a post request lauching the execution of a notebook.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():

        response = requests.get(
            url=url1,
            json=data,
            headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN }
        )
        notebookDict[item] = json.loads(response.text)

 # [...  some logic to sort notebook dict ...]
    
    for item in listeNomNotebook:
        listeNomNotebook[item].sort()
   
    
    # my post method for executing notebook through api
    if request.method == 'POST':

        #[... some variable ...]

        params = {
        'run_name' : f'{notebook_name}',
        'existing_cluster_id' : cluster_id,
        'notebook_task' : {
                'notebook_path' : f'{pathstr}',
                'base_parameters' : parameters
                        },
                }

     
        response = requests.post(
        url=url2,
        json=params,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN }
        )
return render_template('index.html', data=listeNomNotebook)
```

What i want is, from the response of this POST request, which is a job_id, to execute a GET request with this job_id as a parameters to know the result of the execution, failure or success.

I want then to update the website dinamically to show the lifecycle of the job. By this I mean having my GET request in a loop until the state from the response shows terminated. Here is my test code to do this :

```
job_id = response.json()
        print(job_id)
        state = ""
        while True:

            result = requests.get(
                url= url3,
                json=job_id,
                headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % TOKEN }
            )

            dict_result = result.json()
            life_cycle = dict_result["state"]["life_cycle_state"]
            state = dict_result["state"]["state_message"]
            print(life_cycle)
            if life_cycle == "TERMINATED":
                state = dict_result["state"]["result_state"]
                print(state)
                break
            
            sleep(10)
```

I tryed to use ajax but the CORS policy wouldn't let me use that solution (even with an add on on my browser and using flask-cors).

How can i show the result of my notebook on my index page dynamically ? Showing the lifecycle : pending, running , terminated.
And then showing the result : Success or Failure.

All of this is part of the response from the GET request of the databricks api :
api/2.0/jobs/runs/get

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it in this order:

- Post to `/` to start the request, get the `job_id` in the frontend.
- In the front-end, periodically query for job status.

In case the problem is with CORS, then please open a question concerning that after verifying that existing answers don't work. There could be many reasons why you get CORS errors, be sure to state the actual blocker.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, I'll do another post then with ajax on the front end.